# Overcoming changes to persistent message classes in Akka Persistence

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

Let's say I start out with a Akka Persistence system like this:

```
case class MyMessage(x: Int)

class MyProcessor extends Processor {
  def receive = {
    case Persistent(m @ MyMessage) => m.x
    //...
  }
}
```

And then someday I change it to this:

```
case class MyMessage(x: Int, y: Int)

class MyProcessor extends Processor {
  def receive = {
    case Persistent(m @ MyMessage) => m.x + m.y
    //...
  } 
}
```

After I deploy my new system, when the instance of `MyProcessor` tries to restore its state, the journaled messages will be of the former case class. Because it is expecting the latter type, it will throw an `OnReplayFailure`, rendering the processor useless. Question is: if we were to assume an absent `y` can equal `0` (or whatever) is there a best practice to overcome this? For example, perhaps using an `implicit` to convert from the former message to the latter on recovery?

Comment: If it's important that no messages are lost, I would keep the old Message format for backward compatibility (may be under the other name) for a while after the switch (so that you can process the rest of the old messages together with the new ones).

Comment: @Ashalynd In my situation, theoretically, a client could restart an old processor years after its demise. Keeping old code for backwards compatibility could get very bloated. But that'd be the solution if no other.

Comment: That makes it nasty, but otoh, perhaps years after those messages aren't relevant anymore. You can also define a "catch-all" matcher for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka uses Java serialization by default and says that for a long-term project we should use a proper alternative. This is because Java serialization is very difficult to evolve over time. Akka recommends using either Google Protocol Buffers, Apache Thrift or Apache Avro.

With Google Protocol Buffers, for example, in your case you'd be writing something like:

```
if (p.hasY) p.getY else 0
```

Akka explains all that in a nice article (admittedly it's not very Google-able):

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/persistence-schema-evolution.html

and even explains your particular use case of adding a new field to an existing message type:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/persistence-schema-evolution.html#Add_fields

A blog post the Akka documentation recommends for a comparison of the different serialization toolkits:

http://martin.kleppmann.com/2012/12/05/schema-evolution-in-avro-protocol-buffers-thrift.html